# Extract end of sub-directory names in directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have example sub-directory names such as:

- Test_ABCDEF_406_1
- Test_ABCDEF_AOH_1
- Test_ABCDEF_AUQ_1

within a larger directory called Test.

How can I efficiently pull out "ABCDEF_***_*" or everything after Test_ to get the following:

- ABCDEF_406_1
- ABCDEF_AOH_1
- ABCDEF_AUQ_1

Note that the above are folders and not files if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over the pathnames of the subdirectories and use a parameter substitution to delete the initial part of them:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for dirpath in Test/Test_*/; do
    # Because of the pattern used above, we know that
    # "$dirpath" starts with the string "Test/Test_",
    # and this means we know we can delete that:

    # But first delete that trailing /
    dirpath=${dirpath%/}

    shortname=${dirpath#Test/Test_}

    printf 'The shortened name for "%s" is "%s"\n' "$dirpath" "$shortname"
done
```

The substitution `${variable#pattern}` is a standard substitution that will delete the (shortest) match of `pattern` from the *start* of the value `$variable`.

Likewise, `${variable%pattern}`, used to delete the trailing `/` in the code, deletes the shortest match of `pattern` from the *end* of the value `$variable`.

Testing on the following directory tree:

```
.
`-- Test/
    |-- Test_ABCDEF_406_1/
    |-- Test_ABCDEF_AOH_1/
    `-- Test_ABCDEF_AUQ_1/
```

the code would produce

```
The shortened name for "Test/Test_ABCDEF_406_1" is "ABCDEF_406_1"
The shortened name for "Test/Test_ABCDEF_AOH_1" is "ABCDEF_AOH_1"
The shortened name for "Test/Test_ABCDEF_AUQ_1" is "ABCDEF_AUQ_1"
```

Comment: Isn't that syntax specific to `bash`?

Comment: @AlexisWilke None of this is `bash`-specific.  This would work on any shell that is aiming to be POSIX-compliant.  `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `yash`, `ksh`, ...

Comment: @Kusalananda So if I just wanted the output ABCDEF_406_1, ABCDEF_AOH_1, etc., do I just need to do: print $shortname ?

Comment: @ASinha You have the short name in `$shortname`, so you would output only that or do whatever it is that you actually want it for. I outputted a bit more to illustrate how to do it, but you could use `printf '%s\n' "$shortname"`, or just `echo "$shortname"` if you were sure that it would be safe (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803).

Comment: @Kusalananda great, that worked perfectly. Thank you!